# Xamarin, How do I clear data from pickers and Entry right away. Using the montemagno Xamarin.plugins.setting

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

When i clicked Clear, I want to clear  saved data from my pickers and entry.  But i click it, it doesn't clear right away. I have to close the app then re-open then it's clear.  I tried to push empty strings "" but it gave me errors then re open again it froze my app.

```
void clearHandle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{   
Settings.ClearAllData();
}

//then added to push empty string but got error
//UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");


void clearHandle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
DisplayAlert("EDIT", "Are you sure you want to clear data ", "OK");
nameEntry.Text = "";
nxPicker.SelectedItem = "";
locationPicker1.SelectedItem = "";
locationPicker2.SelectedItem = "";
locationPicker3.SelectedItem = "";
locationPicker4.SelectedItem = "";
locationPicker5.SelectedItem = "";
locationPicker6.SelectedItem = "";
locationPicker7.SelectedItem = "";
locationPicker8.SelectedItem = "";
Settings.ClearAllData();

}
```

Comment: "it doesn't clear right away" - what does this mean?  Do you mean the pickers on the page do not clear?  Or that the saved data is not cleared?  You have posted two different versions of the same function - which ones causes the problem?

Comment: ,the first  Handle does clear the datas but i have to close the app then re-open it, then all data are clear.  But I want to see data get clear on spot. I don't have to close then re open app.   On the 2nd Handle I tried to add "" empty string trying to push empty string on it.  but that cause null error. So the 2nd approach didn't work...

Comment: where is the code for Settings.ClearAllData()?  And again, when you say "clear the datas" do you mean the saved Settings OR do you mean the actual UI pickers that are on the screen?  They are two different things.

Comment: also, if you read the docs, the default value of Picker SelectedIndex is -1, so that seems like an obvious thing to try

Comment: you are right.  they are two different things.  I was trying to clear the SAVED data hoping to clear from the UIpickers... I'm going to thinker a bit with these advised you gave me.

Comment: Ok found it after clearing need the push the new page where settings are : now they are all clear: void clearHandle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{   
Settings.ClearAllData();
Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SettingsPage());
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly Click events sometimes run on delegates in Xamarin, both Forms and Native. So I'd suggest wrapping your clear request in a UI dispatcher delegate like so:

```
void clearHandle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{   
    Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=>{
        Settings.ClearAllData();
    });    
}


void clearHandle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DisplayAlert("EDIT", "Are you sure you want to clear data ", "OK");
    nameEntry.Text = "";
    nxPicker.SelectedItem = "";
    locationPicker1.SelectedItem = "";
    locationPicker2.SelectedItem = "";
    locationPicker3.SelectedItem = "";
    locationPicker4.SelectedItem = "";
    locationPicker5.SelectedItem = "";
    locationPicker6.SelectedItem = "";
    locationPicker7.SelectedItem = "";
    locationPicker8.SelectedItem = "";
    Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=>{
        Settings.ClearAllData();
    });
}
```

Comment: is that the same as:  void clearHandle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e) { Settings.ClearAllData(); Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SettingsPage()); }

Comment: Nope not exactly, it basically ensures that any work relating to the UI is carried out on the thread responsible for having rendered it, the UI thread can't handle cross thread interactions for various reasons.